# FCNTL returns errno - Invalid argument

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, fcntl

I can't figure out why my fcntl keeps saying "Invalid argument". Please, help. If I understand it correctly I should fill my flock (the one that I pass to fcntl) with data that points to a byte I want to check.

```
  int byteno;
  printf(ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "Insert byte number: " ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
  scanf("%d\n", &byteno);

  struct flock* fl = malloc(sizeof(flock));
  fl -> l_type = F_GETLK;
  fl -> l_whence = SEEK_SET;
  fl -> l_start = byteno;
  fl -> l_len = 1;
  fl -> l_pid = getpid();

  if(fcntl(descr, F_GETLK, fl) == -1){
    perror(ANSI_COLOR_RED "Error while getting info about locks" ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
    free(fl);
    continue;
  }

  if(!(fl -> l_type == F_UNLCK)){
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW "Other proccess has a lock here. PID = %d" ANSI_COLOR_RESET, fl -> l_pid);
    continue;
  }
```

Comment: The dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should never be surrounded by spaces.

Comment: POSIX ([`<fcntl.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/fcntl.h.html)) says: _`short  l_type` — Type of lock; F_RDLCK, F_WRLCK, F_UNLCK._  You're supplying `F_GETLK`; this is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> F_GETLK (struct flock *)
>
> On input to this call, lock describes a lock we would like to place on the file. **If the lock could be placed, fcntl() does not actually place it, but returns F_UNLCK in the l_type field of lock and leaves the other fields of the structure unchanged.** If one or more incompatible locks would prevent this lock  being placed, then fcntl() returns details about one of these locks in the l_type, l_whence, l_start, and l_len fields of lock and sets l_pid to be the PID of the process holding that lock.

`F_GETLK` is not used to get information about a lock, but rather to '*test whether applying the specified lock would work*'.

Try the following example. Run it twice within the 5 second window.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(void) {
    int fd;
    struct flock fl_info;
    int ret;

    fd = open("./test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open()");
        return;
    }

    memset(&fl_info, 0, sizeof(fl_info));

    /* try to get a WRITE lock on the entire file (l_len == zero) */
    fl_info.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    fl_info.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fl_info.l_start = 0;
    fl_info.l_len = 0;

    ret = fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &fl_info);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("fcntl(F_GETLK)");
        return;
    }

    if (fl_info.l_type != F_UNLCK) {
        printf("Too bad... it's already locked... by pid=%d\n", fl_info.l_pid);
        return;
    }

    /* try to apply a write lock */
    fl_info.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    ret = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl_info);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("fcntl(F_SETLK)");
        return;
    }

    printf("Success!\n");

    sleep(5);

    printf("I'm done, bye!\n")

    return;
}
```

---

Note also that it is not necessary to `malloc()` storage for the `struct flock`.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't see the mistake here. I've tried to change fl -> l_type = F_SETLK, but still it is not running.

Comment: `l_type` needs to be set to the type of lock you would like to apply... not to the operation you would like to carry out. Look at my example - `fl_info.l_type = F_WRLCK;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now and I understand it now as well.